# Why did Thomas gave his son a newspaper clipping which contains Black's phone number?

Tags: plot-explanation, extremely-loud-and-incredibly-close

In *Extremely Loud and Incredibly Close* Oskar looks at a newspaper clipping that his father, Thomas, gave him, circling the words "notstop looking" in an article, he turns over the clipping and finds a phone number that is circled.

Vase belongs to Black & but Thomas owned it by buying from Abby's ex-husband, William.

Then why did Thomas gave his son a newspaper clipping which contains Black's phone number?